# EMV development

Tags: c++, emv

I am new to EMV development.
I would appreciate if someone could give some guide
how to communicate with EMV based card (e.g., 
read card owner, expiry date, etc.) preferably using C++?
Any information (samples, references to links online, etc.)
how to do this welcome.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: it seems you redirected me to page of some product. I am interested myself how can one implement a solution based on C++ to "talk" to EMV based card, and get say owner, etc. information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll have to go through the EMV specification : http://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223

If you just want to play a little bit around, on Windows you can use the [PC/SC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/SC) [Windows API](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742533.aspx). If you're ready to switch to C#, [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17013/Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET) is a really nice tutorial, with examples.

But if you intend to eventually perform full EMV transactions, it'll be way cheaper and faster to buy an existing EMV level 2 kernel (ex : from http://www.level2kernel.com/emv_kernel.html).

Comment: can you tell me what is EMV kernel? and when I need to use it? Do I need to use it if I need to read some basic info about the card?

Comment: An EMV kernel is a library that will abstract the hardware layer (the EMV chip reader) and manage all exchanges with the card. You don't need one if you only want to access basic information about the card, but you'll have to implement the application selection process (PSE) and the required parts of the dialog yourself. Your first step should be to read the EMV specification.

Comment: ok thanks. I saw some examples which allow to access that data either through PSE or using AID, am I correct? I found this sample: http://code.google.com/p/cardreadergui/. ps. I will check specifications you mention too

Comment: The sample seems interesting, even though I didn't test it. You'll have to use both the PSE (Payment System Environment) and the AID (Application IDentifier) to access your card info. The PSE is more like a file system which will tell you what application(s) is(are) available on the card. Then, you can select the application you want to use using its AID. You'll find all details about this process in the EMV spec.

Comment: ok thanks Nicolas, so far I had a feeling you could access applications on the card *either* using PSE (if one is available) or AID, seems I was wrong? if I have some other issue in future I will let you know. ps. am I the only one who thinks there isn't much info about this stuff on the net?

Comment: You're right. Think of the PSE as a file system, and your AID as an executable. You can't use the latter without the former. And you're also right about the lack of good tutorials and examples on the web. The EMV specs are detailed, but not very user friendly...

Comment: Final question. We said there are two ways to select app. (1) using PSE or (2) using AID. My question is: what if I use method (2) always? Is it OK? And never use method (1) for example. The reason I am asking it maybe less work to use method (2) than method (1) - so if method (2) does all that method (1), why use method(1)?